# Multiple forms on one page

Tags: django-forms

For example if i have 3 forms on one page, how can i check in my view function which form was posted?

```
form1 = FormClass1
form2 = FormClass2
form3 = FormClass3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All* of them will be posted unless you put them in separate form tags with separate submit buttons.

Comment: They have separate submit buttons and separate form tags.

Comment: I have only this thought: if `form1(request.POST): do something`, `elif form2(request.POST): do soemthing`, `elif form3(request.POST): do something`?
And i have one more burning me question: it is possible somehow to take a look, maybe in python shell, at bolded structure of request object from, for example, my own testing sended request?

Comment: If you have three separate form tags, then why are you sending them all to the same view?

Comment: Good question. There is no reason to send them to this same view. Thank You.